# How to set localStorage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, storage

This is a to do list program. I want to save my to do list page when the page is refreshed. All the css and other functions work properly. I think my mistake is using the wrong variable within the store function My current attempt still isn't working. The attempt is at the end of the script. What did I do wrong?

```js
  var inputItem = document.getElementById("inputItem");
inputItem.focus();

function addItem(list, input) {
  var inputItem = this.inputItem;
  var list = document.getElementById(list);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");

  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = "X";
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });

  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.id = "check";
  checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    labelText.style.textDecoration = checkBox.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none';
  });

  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var labelText = document.createElement("span");
  labelText.innerText = input.value;

  label.appendChild(checkBox);
  label.appendChild(labelText);

  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

  list.appendChild(listItem);
  inputItem.focus();
  inputItem.select();
  return false;

}

function store() {
  var html = listItem.innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem("page", html);
}

function retrieve() {
  var html = localStorage.getItem("page");
  listItem.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<h1 align="center"> To-Do List </h1>

<body>
  <div id="outerDiv">
    <form onsubmit="return addItem('list', this.inputItem)">
      <input type="text" id="inputItem" onfocus="this.value=''" onselect="this.value=''" placeholder="Enter a Task">
      <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="innerDiv">
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means. Error messages? Expected results? Observed results?

Comment: You haven't called `store` or `retrieve` anywhere so it's hard to say if they work or not.  Try calling `retrieve` after the [document is ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onDOMContentLoaded)  or the [window has finished loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and `store` [before the document unloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).

Comment: You haven't called store anywhere, why you expect it works?

Comment: Its my first time using the local storage in a function. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store only value instead of whole html.

```
var inputItem = document.getElementById("inputItem");
inputItem.focus();
function addItem(list, value, onLoad) {
  var inputItem = this.inputItem;
  var list = document.getElementById(list);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = "X";
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.id = "check";
  checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    labelText.style.textDecoration = checkBox.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none';
  });
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var labelText = document.createElement("span");
  labelText.innerText = value;
  label.appendChild(checkBox);
  label.appendChild(labelText);
  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
  list.appendChild(listItem);
  inputItem.focus();
  inputItem.select();
  if(!onLoad) {
    this.store(value);
  }
  return false;
}
function store(value) {
  var list = localStorage.getItem("list");
  if(list) {
    list = list.split(",");
    list.push(value);                 ;
  } else {
    list = [value];
  }
  localStorage.setItem("list", list.toString());
}
window.onload = function() {
  var list = localStorage.getItem("list");
  if(list) {
    list = list.split(",");
    list.forEach(function(li){
      this.addItem("list", li, true);
    },this);
  }
}
```

And You have to change your html

```
<form onsubmit="return addItem('list', this.inputItem.value)">
      <input type="text" id="inputItem" onfocus="this.value=''" onselect="this.value=''" placeholder="Enter a Task">
      <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Just a link answer is not the best way, post here relevate parts of the code. btw. link is not clickable please fix. :) [Tip on answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)